# Date changed to strange values in feature class when uploaded to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service, timeslider, datetime

I have a feature layer in ArcGIS Desktop running 10.1. It has a Date column with it. In ArcMap, this layer also has Time enabled with Time Zone set to "UTC+10:00 Canberra, Melbourne , Sydney" and "Values are adjusted for daylight savings" checked. The values in the DATETIME column are "dd/MM/yyyy 12:00:00 AM" in the designated time zone so it only shows the date part. It seems all good so far.

[image]

[image]

When I published the MXD file to ArcGIS Online, however, all the values in the DATETIME columns were changed to strange values.

[image]

I know ArcGIS Online would automatically convert the date values to suit the Time Zone of where you view the data. As I have set the correct Time Zone in ArcMap, ArcGIS Online should have shown the correct date values.

Even if ArcGIS Online hadn't done the conversion and did recognise the values as **UTC**, the date values should have been shown as the UTC time or the date time + 11 hrs. For instance, "23/11/2017" in ArcMap would be "23/11/2017"  or "23/11/2017, 11:00 AM" in Australian Eastern Standard Time with Daylight Savings. The "11/22/2017, 3:00 PM" is totally unexplainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datetimes have been converted to USA format (mm/dd/yyyy).  If your time is going from 23rd at 11am to 22nd at 3pm, the datetimes are being converted from AEST to Alaska Standard Time Zone.

Check this site for timezone info: [AEST to AKST](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20171020T000000&p1=240&p2=tz_akst)

A workaround would be to calculate the datetime field into a text field prior to publishing to AGOL.

You should also try converting the datatimes to UTC before publishing.

Comment: I think converting the datetime values to UTC before publishing is my way to go.